# Spinner in the toolbar appears when I search - Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a drawer navigation and I switch between fragments, in the Fragment ONE I have a spinner in the toolbar. In the Fragment TWO, I don't want the spinner, so I remove the spinner with the property "visibility=GONE" and that works.

BUT, in the Fragment TWO, doing the following steps, something strange really happens

1. Tap in the search icon
2. The search view appears in the toolbar
3. I tap cancel
4. The search view collapse, and the spinner from the Fragment ONE shows up

I have tried to use this listener "OnActionExpandListener" in the search icon to hide the spinner again when user taps cancel, but it doesn't work.

any ideas?

Drawer navigation where I set up the toolbar

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_dropdown"/>

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/gray_light_divider_list_drawerNav"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray_light_background_list_drawerNav"
        />
```

Drawer navigation Activity method OnCreate, where I setup the the toolbar

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

This is how I switch between fragments

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

Using the ActionBarDrawerToggle in the method onDrawerOpened, I remove the spinner, so that means that every time the Drawer Navigation is open I removed the spinner like this

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_nav);
 spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This is the OnActionExpandListener in the Fragment TWO

```
 MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener searchOnActionExpandListener = new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_nav);
 spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where you set up and hide the spinner? And is the spinner in a layout exclusive to fragment 1 or is it in a portion that is common to both fragment 1 and 2 and you are just hiding it when fragment 2 shows up?

Comment: Hi Sunil, the spinner is in a portion that is common to both. And I hide the spinner every time that the Drawer Navigation is open, and it shows up when I replace the Fragment ONE

Comment: I edited my question with the code

Comment: Hmm.. the code above seems to be fine. I was hoping to see the code where you tap to expand the search view. But as a workaround (and not an elegant one at that), can you try adding a listener to the "Cancel" button (or item) with the statement View.GONE instead of having it in the OnActionExpandListener? Again, this is just a guess from what I'm seeing here. This code seems alright - could you edit your question with the code that shows how you expand and collapse your search view and where you have  defined View.GONE originally?

Comment: when I mean "Cancel", I'm actually talking about when the "back" button from the toolbar is pressed, which cancels the search. That's why I'm using the OnActionExpandListener, to get notified when the search view is collapsed. Now the listener is working, it's triggered when I press the back button, but the spinner doesn't disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I did the following.

I removed the spinner in the toolbar so it looks like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And I started to add the spinner in the fragment ONE programatically

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if(toolbar.findViewWithTag("spinner_nav")==null) {
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
        spinner.setTag("spinner_nav");

        //Setting up the adapter
        AdapterFragmentOne spinnerAdapter = new AdapterFragmentOne(getActivity(), array);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

        if (spinner != null) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        }
        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationListener);

        toolbar.addView(spinner);
    }
```

In my Drawer navigation Activity I remove the spinner when the drawer is opened, I execute

```
    //Removing the spinner view
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) toolbar.findViewWithTag("spinner_nav");
    toolbar.removeView(spinner);
```

Comment: You deserve a nobel prize for this.